# Convert number to percentage of random

Tags: c#, winforms, random

I am looking at having a option to specify how often something should run, in terms of a percentage.

So I would have a textbox, that takes a number 0-100 to detirmine a percentage.  I want to then take this number, and convert in into a matching random statement.

So for example:

```
textPercentage.text = "10"
```

would be changed to something like:

```
if (rnd.Next(1, 11) = 1)
{
   do();
}
```

What is the best way to convert that numerical value to a matching random statement?

Comment: Is your TextBox WPF or WinForms?  I'm betting it is WinForms but I thought I'd ask anyhow.

Comment: Yes, WinForms, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Michael I see like that: random form 1 - 10, then add conditions: if, value is 1 and no else so this is 1/10 and thi is the 10 percentage, if value is 1 and next value is 4 so we have two values so this is 2/10 = 20%. Am I going to right way of your thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var i = int.Parse(textPercentage.Text);
if (rnd.Next(1, 101) <= i)
{
    do();
}
```

You might want to use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) in stead of `int.Parse` to gracefully handle non digit inputs.

Comment: Thanks, so simple, I was making it much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

First get your value back into an `int`.

- In WPF, this is easy because you just databind to an `int` property.
- In WinForms you use the `int.Parse` method to get the value back: `int.Parse(textBox.Text)`

If you use the values `0-100` you can use something similar to your original code, as-is.

```
int value = int.Parse(textBox.Text);

if(rnd.Next(0, 100) < value)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Otherwise, just add one to both the start and end values:

```
int value = int.Parse(textBox.Text);

if(rnd.Next(1, 101) <= value)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

The first one is simpler, so I'd go with it :)